# The efficient way to convert datatype in Matlab (double vs. im2double)

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I want to convert a truecolor image to double precision, and as far as I know there are two ways to do that:

1. `double(rgb_img);`
2. `im2double(rgb_img);`

Which one is more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not focus on which one is more efficient. You need to know that they serve different purposes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought they do the same thing. That's why I was wondering the efficience between them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a benchmarking code to compare `double` against `im2double` even though they don't necessarily produce the same results as explained in the other solution(s) -

```
N_arr = [100 200 500 1000 2000 4000]; %// datasize array
timeall = zeros(4,numel(N_arr));
for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)

    rgb_img = uint8(randi([0 255],N_arr(k1))); %// Input to functions

    f = @() double(rgb_img);
    timeall(1,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() im2double(rgb_img);
    timeall(2,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
end
figure,hold on,grid on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:),'-ro'),plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:),'-kx')
legend('DOUBLE','IM2DOUBLE'),
xlabel('Datasize ->'),ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

Result -

[image]

Now, this makes sense because internally `im2double` calls `double`.

Now, assuming you are dealing with `uint8` images, to have the same functionality with `double`, you need to scale it down afterwards. So you need to edit the function handle accordingly -

```
f = @() double(rgb_img)./255;
```

The plot result then were -

[image]

So, apparently not much of a difference now.

Answer (score 5):

They both are different.

`im2double` converts the range of an image between `0-1` if the datatype is `uint8` or `uint16`. If the datatype is `single` or `logical`, `im2double` calls `double` (and doesn't scale the image range). For `double` datatype it just remains unchanged (neither the precision changes, nor the image range).

If you already have a double precision image, then you shouldn't call `im2double`, it will NOT rescale your data. You can type `edit im2double` and look at the code. If you *just* want to convert to double precision (without changing the image range), then you should call `double`. Otherwise call `im2double` but make sure, your data is not of `single`, `double` or `logical` type.

Example:

```
img=imread('cameraman.tif'); %datatype is uint8
img1=double(img); %just converts to double precision, image range between 0-255
img2=im2double(img); %converts to double precision and scales image range between 0-1

img=double(imread('cameraman.tif')); %even single datatype will give the same results
img1=double(img); %redundant since image is already double, image range 0-255
img2=im2double(img); %redundant since image is already double, image range 0-255
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. Your answer gave me more than I thought I need to know. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guessed that you wouldn't know the difference between those two when you asked for bench-marking. Since im2double calls double, the latter one will mostly be faster, *in appropriate situations*.