# Equivalent im2double function in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

In MATLAB, the following code reads in an image and normalizes the values between `[0.0,1.0]`:

```
img=im2double(imread('image.jpg'))
```

I would like to perform this in OpenCV Python.  Is there an equivalent function to do this?

I have tried the following code, but its asking for source `IplImage`.  Also, what would be the equivalent to `imread` in Python?

```
def im2double(im):
    mat = cvGetMat(im);
    if CV_MAT_DEPTH(mat.type)==CV_64F:
       return mat
    im64f = array(size(im), 'double')
    cvConvertScale(im, im64f, 1.0, 0.0)
    return im64f
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would avoid using the old `cv` module and use `cv2` instead as these use `numpy` arrays.  `numpy` arrays operate very similar to arrays and matrices in MATLAB.

In any case,  [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) in MATLAB normalizes an image such that the minimum intensity is 0 and the maximum intensity is 1.  You can achieve that by the following relationship, given a pixel `in` from the image `img`:

```
out = (in - min(img)) / (max(img) - min(img))
```

Therefore, you would need to find the minimum and maximum of the image and apply the above operation to every pixel in the image.  In the case of multi-channel images, we would find the **global** minimum and maximum over all channels and apply the same operation to all channels independently.

The short answer to your question is to use [`cv2.normalize`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize) like so:

```
out = cv2.normalize(img.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

The first input is the source image, which we convert to `float`.  The second input is the output image, but we'll set that to `None` as we want the function call to return that for us.  The third and fourth parameters specify the minimum and maximum values you want to appear in the output, which is 0 and 1 respectively, and the last output specifies **how** you want to normalize the image.  What I described falls under the `NORM_MINMAX` flag.

Your other question is with regards to reading in an image.  To read in an image with `cv2`, use [`cv2.imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread).  The input into this function is a string that contains the file you want to load in.  Therefore, you'd call the above function like so:

```
img = cv2.imread('....') # Read image here
out = cv2.normalize(img.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) # Convert to normalized floating point
```

---

However, if you'd like to write something yourself, we can very easily do that using `numpy` operations.

As such, write your function like so:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def im2double(im):
    min_val = np.min(im.ravel())
    max_val = np.max(im.ravel())
    out = (im.astype('float') - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
    return out
```

You'd then use the code like so:

```
img = cv2.imread('...') # Read in your image
out = im2double(img) # Convert to normalized floating point
```

## Edit - September 29, 2016

More recent versions of MATLAB now simply divide all of the numbers by the largest value supported by that datatype.  For example, for `uint8` the largest value is 255 while for `uint16` the largest value is 65535.

If you wanted to reimplement this for more recent versions of MATLAB, you can use the [`numpy.iinfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) function to infer what the smallest and largest values of the datatype are and convert accordingly.  Simply access the largest value and divide all elements in your image by this number.  Make sure you convert the image to a floating-point representation first:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def im2double(im):
    info = np.iinfo(im.dtype) # Get the data type of the input image
    return im.astype(np.float) / info.max # Divide all values by the largest possible value in the datatype
```

Comment: You write, "im2double in MATLAB normalizes an image such that the minimum intensity is 0 and the maximum intensity is 1". Then you show the stretching equation on the next line. However, I don't think `im2double` does that, nor does it say so in the documentation. For example, take this snippet: `img=uint8(randi([45 175],25,25,3)); img1=im2double(img);`. On my machine, `img1` lies in `[0.1765,0.6863]` not 0 to 1. Either I am misunderstanding or there is a mistake here. You can see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26709885/1586200) handling a similar issue.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar They may have changed it as previous versions of MATLAB did in fact normalize the range from `[0,1]` and this was the behaviour that I have seen in the past during my PhD.  They may have now simply divided by the largest number supported by that datatype.  I wrote this post when I had R2013a and they did in fact normalize.

Comment: Once you confirm this, if possible, write this as a note in your answer. Otherwise instead of just converting from [0,1], people will do linear stretching.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar That's what `im2double` did in the past.  It did do a linear stretching.  Also note that beginning of the introduction to this question: *"In MATLAB, the following code reads in an image and normalizes the values between `[0.0,1.0]`:"*.  I'm not able to give you confirmation now as I don't have a copy of such an older version of MATLAB, but take my word for it that it did to linear stretching on top of converting to `double` precision.

Comment: I am not saying that MATLAB didn't do it in the past. I take your word for that. Since neither the question nor the answer mentions anything about this getting applied only to older MATLAB versions, people will assume that this is how we should implement `im2double` even now. However, currently `im2double` now just scales image by an appropriate factor (255 or 65535) and brings it within 0 to 1. So I am asking if you want to add this note. That's all. If you don't think this is needed, let it be. No issues.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Changed.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Have a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: From some of my experiments I concluded that opencv can't understand float64 very well (I couldn't run getRectSubPix), thus I'd recommend converting to float32, for example by the np.asarray function, passing an argument dtype=np.float32 or passing float32 explicitly to the astype function.

Comment: @m3h0w take note that this is performing the equivalent operation from MATLAB such that the conversion brings the type to 64-bit in that environment. This is why that type is used. Unfortunately your experiences are beyond the scope of this question and answer, though valid.