# Equivalent of MATLAB imshow(I,[ ]) for python OpenCv;

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv

I am converting an image processing code from MATLAB to Python using
OpenCv(Python). My original image (our friend Lena) shown below read using the following command shows fine using imshow:

`image = cv2.imread('Lena.bmp',0)`

I add some Gaussian noise to the image

`image_with_noise = image + 20*np.random.randn(256,256)`

When I do imshow (as shown below), I don't see the image with noise as I expect.

`cv2.imshow('image',image_with_noise)`

`cv2.waitKey(0)`

`cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

However, the analogous MATLAB command imshow(image, [ ] ) seems to work fine.

Is there any way to understand or fix this? Your inputs are appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Original image]

[image]

Comment: what's the type of `image_with_noise`? You probably need to convert back to uint8 to display it properly

Comment: BTW, that's not the _correct_ Lena image :D

Comment: The type is float64 when I do Image_with_noise.dtype. Thank you, trying your suggestion now. Haha, true, the prof seems to like this lena better than the old lena

Comment: Dear Miki, it does work now having converted it to uint8. I am still new to image processing. Any explanations why it worked? Thanks

Comment: uint8 images are displayed in the range [0,255], while float images are displayed in the range [0,1]. So, what you saw is that every value above 1 was displayed as white.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes complete sense now.

Comment: This post may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100722/equivalent-im2double-function-in-opencv-python/29104511#29104511

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the comment by Miki which helped me resolve the issue. I am posting the answer here in case others run into a similar problem.

The issue was the type of the image_with_noise data. When I do 
`image_with_noise.dtype`, it returns a float64. Since float images are displayed in the range [0,1], any value exceeding 1 is shown as white(which is exactly what was happening).

The solution was to convert the image to uint8 where the display range is [0,255]. This can be done using the following one liner in cv2

`image_with_noise_uint8=cv2.convertScaleAbs(image_with_noise)`

With this, the noisy image displays as expected!

[image: noisy_image]